# Python "open" file got 'TypeError: function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)'

Tags: python

I've had a piece of code which basically read a txt file from directory.

```
def img2vector(filename):
  returnVect=zeros((1,1024))
  fr=open(filename)
  for i in range(32):
    lineStr=fr.readline()
    for j in range(32):
      returnVect[0,32*i+j]=int(lineStr[j])
  return returnVect
```

When I run img2vector(PATHTOMYFILE) I've got the error message:

```
    fr=open(filename)
TypeError: function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

But, when I try:

`fr=open(PATHTOMYFILE)`

it's correct without any problem.

Comment: In *what context* did you try the `open(PATHTOMYFILE)` call? because that's *not the same function*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you define (or import) a function called `open()` that shadows the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @sshashank124: It is hard to be sure, but I suspect that the OP tried that other command in a different context (i.e. he was calling the built-in `open()`).

Comment: Possibly, It's hard to be sure since the question is so limited in providing __all__ the relavant code.

Answer (score 0):

You must have imported both os and numpy

You can do

```
from numpy import *
import operator
import os
```